# Google Map getting crashed after drawing around more than 1300 markers with custom color setting icon property

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, markers

I can draw more than around 8000 default red markers without setting icon property for marker.
But I want to draw markers with different colors depending upon marker's value.
In XCOde I get below warning:-

```
((null)) was false: Reached the max number of texture atlases, can not allocate more.
((null)) was false: Failed to get the icon for the given CGImageRef.
((null)) was false: Failed to allocate texture space for marker
```

from Google Map SDK & after that around 1300 markers it gets crashed.
Is there any other way to set different colors to markers without crashing for more than 1300 markers.

I am setting marker's colour like below:-

```
marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: strColor))

 func getColorsFromString(strColor:String) -> UIColor
{
    var color = UIColor()
    
    switch strColor {
    case "GREEN":
        color = UIColor.green
    case "YELLOW":
        color = UIColor.yellow
    case "RED":
        color = UIColor.red
    case "ORANGE":
        color = UIColor.orange
    case "BLUE":
        color = UIColor.blue
    case "CYAN":
        color = UIColor.cyan
    case "MAGENTA":
        color = UIColor.magenta
        
    default:
        color = UIColor.red
        print("default color")
    }
    return color
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to use struct of image? Wo do not need to call GMSMarker.markerImage() thousands times.

```
struct MarkerImage {
  static let green = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "GREEN"))
  static let yellow = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "YELLOW"))
  static let red = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "RED"))
}

func getIcon(color: String) -> Image {
  switch(color) {
     case "GREEN": return MarkerImage.green
     case "YELLOW": return MarkerImage.yellow
     default: return MarkerImage.red
  }
}

marker.icon = getIcon(color)
```

If it works, we could create an enum of the color names, and extend that to return an image.

Comment: thank you for solution.Can you provide solution without considering SWiftUI ?

Comment: ??? This is not SwiftUI code. It is just Swift code.

Comment: i am getting error while creating struct like "Cannot find type 'Image' in scope"

Comment: Did you add 'import UIKit'?

Comment: yes .I added that already.

Comment: can you provide swift file for it ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I removed 'Image' from the struct code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [winner.ktw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711511/winner-ktw) for this solution  This solution didn't work directly but I made a few changes then it worked for me. Because of your solution, I got an idea. So thanks once again!
here I am sharing my edited version of [winner.ktw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711511/winner-ktw) code.

```
struct MarkerImage{
static var shared = MarkerImage()

    lazy var  green = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "GREEN"))
    lazy var  yellow = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "YELLOW"))
    lazy var  red = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: self.getColorsFromString(strColor: "RED"))

    func getColorsFromString(strColor:String) -> UIColor {
        var color = UIColor()
    
        switch strColor {
            case "GREEN":
                    color = UIColor.green
            case "YELLOW":
                color = UIColor.yellow
            default:
                color = UIColor.red
        }
        return color
    }
}

func getIcon(color: String) -> UImage {
   switch(color) {
        case "GREEN": return MarkerImage.shared.green
        case "YELLOW": return MarkerImage.shared.yellow
        default: return MarkerImage.shared.red
   }

}
```